# travic-ci build failing with django project

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

I am trying to setup travis-ci for the first time with a django project of mine and I am getting this trace in the `travis` output...

```
0.17s$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named py
The command "python manage.py migrate" exited with 1.
```

Now I can see that it is looking for a module named `py` instead of running the `manage.py` file but I don't see why that would happen, and I have found numerous resources online that have stated to run a command like that in the travi.yml file (heres one: https://gist.github.com/ndarville/3625246)

here is my travis.yml file:

```
script:
  - python manage.py migrate
  - python manage.py test
```

Now before I go running off and trying to get it to run by installing another module like `tox` or `nose` I would like to know if it is possible to do it this why and why it is failing and where to find the info in the docs... Thanks